# Visual SOAP editor for Eclipse

Tags: soap, jboss, eclipse-plugin, jbossfuse

I want a visual editor to make the connection between a SOAP endpoint. I have a list of SOAP web services and I want to build a workflow with a visual editor or a simple configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

in version 8 of jboss developer studio you find all plugins: fuse tooling, switchyard and BPEL.